Why is the gizmo not showing up?
I was facing some issue about the arrow not appearing when choosing vertices (the dot thing on corners or edges) earlier. I thought it was the gizmo trolling me, but after checking in with an unsaved new project, turns out the arrows.
Maybe was turned off (in the gizmo setting thingy), and when I opened the model I was working on, I found out they went back to the original circle thingy at the bottom, instead of at the dot.
What happened there and how do I fix it?
The 3 colored arrows was at the normal start point, while the actual area they needed to be is up there, the small white dot at the ears


it seems like the issue is that the 3d cursor position was changed, but idk why it was changed aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

This thingy is called a gizmo. You cropped everything from the interface so it's impossible to tell you for sure. My guess is, the Transform Pivot Point is set to 3D Cursor. Try set it to Median Point (the default value).

It seems that you Gizmo's transform pivot point is set to 3D Cursor.
You could move the 3D Cursor around using ⇧ Shift RMB drag, or the dedicated tool in the toolbar:
But most likely you want to operate the gizmo from the center of whatever you select, as it does by default. In that case, you should probably set the transform pivot point back to Median Point using the dropdown menu in the top center of the viewport, or using the pie menu with . if you enabled those in the preferences:


(aka the "middle" of a selection, that way if you select multiple things you operate from their combined center)

Nevermind, turns out I somehow set the pivot to 3D cursor sometimes earlier, if someone sees this and is also having the similiar problem, try pressing the " key, and then chose median

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One-liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
